# Change distance from top to section

Tags: formatting

How can I change the distance from the top of my page to the section title to a specific distance. It is somehow way to far away from the top and I want to fix that.

Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}% If comment this, figure moves to Page 2
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}



%\date{\today}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{style = Matlab-editor}

\pretitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE
  \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=2cm]{ABC}\\[\bigskipamount]
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\title{PEWPEW \textcopyright \\ ABC}

\author{MAX\\
  \texttt{MUSTERMANN}
  \and
  MAX\\
  \texttt{MUSTERFRAU}
}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents 

\newpage
\section{ABC}[h]
\verbatiminput{ABC.txt}

\section{ABC2}
\verbatiminput{ABC2.txt}

\section{ABC3}
\verbatiminput{ABC3.txt}

\newpage
\section{Something else}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.325]{Plot1}
    \caption{WEIRDSTUFF}
\end{figure} 


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.325]{Plot2}
    \caption{CENSORED}
\end{figure} 

\section{PLOTS}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{something}
    \caption{PLOTS}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{somethingtoo}
    \caption{Curves}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\section{Output Variables}
\verbatiminput{mfile.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you use, i.e., the code of a small document that shows the big distance, including the class and all packages that you load? Without this information it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Edited. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Your sections title are on the top of text field. To have smaller margin, you need to change page layout. For example with help of `geometry` package: `\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}` .

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped first of all. Can you tell me how you also can change the distance between the section and the first element on the site then? Like distance(sectionname-figure) or distance(sectionname-txtfile)? Much appreciated mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me convert my comment to the answer:

Your sections title are on the top of text field, however default margins of the article document class are "huge". To have smaller margin, you need to change page layout. This can be done for example with help of geometry package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
...
```

By this your page will look as follows:

[image]

Off-topic: use of `H` option from `float` package for figure placement can cause unexpected problems: large empty space on page bottom (when is no enough room on page for a image). Use this option with care or better, not use it!